# Can Go's `flag` package print usage?

Tags: go

Is it possible for me to customize Go's `flag` package so that it prints a custom usage string? I have an application with current output

```
Usage of ./mysqlcsvdump:
  -compress-file=false: whether compress connection or not
  -hostname="": database host
  -outdir="": where output will be stored
  -password="": database password
  -port=3306: database port
  -single-transaction=true: whether to wrap everything in a transaction or not.
  -skip-header=false: whether column header should be included or not
  -user="root": database user
```

and would rather have something like

```
Usage: ./mysqlcsvdump [options] [table1 table2 ... tableN]

Parameters:
  -compress-file=false: whether compress connection or not
  -hostname="": database host
  -outdir="": where output will be stored
  -password="": database password
  -port=3306: database port
  -single-transaction=true: whether to wrap everything in a transaction or not.
  -skip-header=false: whether column header should be included or not
  -user="root": database user
```

Comment: Personally I like this package way more than the standard flags, it's much more robust and more in line with other languages: https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags . You should give it a try.

Comment: Shameless plug: and another "command line processor" package for Go: https://github.com/speedata/optionparser

Comment: @topskip the abundance of great alternative command line parsers in Go, highlights just how much the standard parser is lacking, sadly.

Comment: The standard `flag` package works for this project. I'll have a look your alterantives when I have a slightly more complicated CLI application to work with. Thanks, though!

Comment: Another is Cobra: https://github.com/spf13/cobra

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by modifying [`flag.Usage`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#pkg-variables):

> ```
> var Usage = func() {
>         fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage of %s:\n", os.Args[0])
>
>         flag.PrintDefaults()
> }
> ```
>
> Usage prints to standard error a usage message documenting all defined
>   command-line flags. The function is a variable that may be changed to
>   point to a custom function.

Example use from outside of `flag`:

```
flag.Usage = func() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "This is not helpful.\n")
}
```

Comment: the current `flag.Usage` default implementation writes to `CommandLine.Output()` rather than `os.Stderr`, which allows you to set it with `flag.CommandLine.SetOutput(io.Writer)`

Comment: and `flag.CommandLine.Output()` gets the current `io.Writer` that the `flag` package is set to. So using `fmt.Fprintf(flag.CommandLine.Output(), ...)` ensures consistent destination output.

Comment: the Usage can be triggered by using go run *.go -h

Answer (score 8):

In Feb 2018, [Go 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#flag) updated the default destination of `flag` output:

> The default Usage function now prints its first line of output to
> CommandLine.Output() instead of assuming os.Stderr, so that the usage
> message is properly redirected for clients using
> CommandLine.SetOutput.

(see also [flag.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.10/src/flag/flag.go#L540))

So if you want to customize your flag usage, don't assume `os.Stderr`, instead use something like:

```
flag.Usage = func() {
    w := flag.CommandLine.Output() // may be os.Stderr - but not necessarily

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Usage of %s: ...custom preamble... \n", os.Args[0])

    flag.PrintDefaults()

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "...custom postamble ... \n")

}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want full customisation over your usage, you need to reimplement the `flag.Usage()` function by using `flag.VisitAll()` to iterate through all the parsed flags. For example:

```
flag.Usage = func() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Custom help %s:\n", os.Args[0])
    
    flag.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "    %v\n", f.Usage) // f.Name, f.Value
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And finally, in Go 1.16.4 we have:

```
// Output returns the destination for usage and error messages. os.Stderr is returned if
// output was not set or was set to nil.
func (f *FlagSet) Output() io.Writer {
    if f.output == nil {
        return os.Stderr
    }
    return f.output
}
```

So, by default it uses `os.Stderr`, otherwise what was set to the output.

Comment: `flag.Output()` first appeared in `go 1.10` (back in [Feb 2018](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#flag)): [flag.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.10/src/flag/flag.go#L312)